# How to deploy a nodejs backend and vuejs frontend to the same Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, amazon-ec2

I have a vuejs frontend and an express nodejs backend. But I don't know how I can deploy both of them to the same Amazon EC2 instance with the same domain name pointing to them. Please can anyone help me with this? Or suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two repos and deploy both backend and frontend as follows

1. Inside your nodejs app, open a folder named **client** and put all the Vue project inside it.
2. If you are using Vue CLI, change your **vue.config.js** as follows to create a dist folder inside the root of the nodejs project like

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
};
```

3. Make all the get/post endpoints of nodejs application start with **/api/** to not get conflict with the path that redirects all the requests to vue client app other than **/api/** paths.
4. Run **npm run build** to create a dist folder inside nodejs root backend folder
5. If you are using express.js, serve dist folder with nodejs express backend like;

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve Vue Dist Folder 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
```

Comment: Thanks @onuriltan. I was able to do that and now I can see my vuejs frontend on my localhost 3000 server port. But the problem now is I can't get information from my database. Please what do I need to configure to solve that?

Comment: What do you mean by get information from database, do you mean you can't get response from api request?

Comment: You can check out [my project](https://github.com/onuriltan/ScrumPoker) which you can deploy to just one container that has both front-end and back-end code in the same repo

Comment: Yes I mean api requests. Only post requests are working fine. Get requests are not. Any idea what could be the cause? I did exactly the same setup as your project.

Comment: Now the GET requests are working fine. I had to remove from your code this line: "app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));" so that my Express route can be assessed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Appreciated, you can put **/api/** naming to all of the api endpoints so you don't need to delete "app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));"

Comment: @Efosa can you accept the answer if it does help :)

Comment: How can I accept the answer? I have checked everywhere but can't find it.

Comment: Click the up arrow at the beginning of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

nodejs with e.g. express can also serve static content. Just put your vuejs files in a [static folder](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express).